# Test <header> tag and data-cy attribute exist in Cypress test

Tags: html, header, cypress

I am using [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress) for testing my site.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<header data-cy="my-header" />
```

I want to test if the header element exist with `data-cy="my-header` attribute, but also if it contains the `<header>` tag.

I have the following:

```
  cy.get('[data-cy=my-header]'
    .get('header')
    .should('be.visible');
```

Is this correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var links = ['Home', 'About', 'Contact']

cy.get('.MuiTab-root').each(($ele, index) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim()).to.equal(links[index])
})
```